# I need a make a heatmap by plotly that shows more information

Tags: r, dplyr, plotly, heatmap, ggplotly

I'd like to be able to make an R plotly heatmap that in addition to show the information about z,  I will have more information which will be text information.

Here's what I mean: I have this data set dataset:

```
library(plotly)
m <- matrix(c(NA, 1,3, 2, NA, 4, 3, 0, NA), nrow = 3, ncol = 3)

fig <- plot_ly(
    x = c("Epilepsy", "PTSD", "Depression"), y = c("Dizziness", "Slowed Thinking/ Decision-making
", "Hearing/Noise Sensitivity
"),
    z = m, type = "heatmap"
)
```

This gives me this output: [image: This is a Plotly heatmap]

However, I need something more when I click each part I have this variable too:

```
p <- matrix(c(NA, "XX","YY", "TT", NA, "ST", "PO", "IU", NA), nrow = 3, ncol = 3)
```

As you can see, this is not numeric and it just provides more information concerning the association.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add your matrix `p` to the `text` attribute, i.e.

```
fig <- plot_ly(
  x = x, 
  y = y,
  z = m, 
  type = "heatmap",
  text = p
)
```

complete code

```
library(plotly)
m <- matrix(c(NA, 1,3, 2, NA, 4, 3, 0, NA), nrow = 3, ncol = 3)
p <- matrix(c(NA, "XX","YY", "TT", NA, "ST", "PO", "IU", NA), nrow = 3, ncol = 3)

fig <- plot_ly(
  x = x, 
  y = y,
  z = m, 
  type = "heatmap",
  text = p
)
fig
```

[image]